# How to add a name to a column that shows (no column name) on the result pane

Tags: sql, inner-join, rename, multiple-columns

I have the following syntax:

```
SELECT t1.cardid, t1.Name, min(t2.record) FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 on t1.tag=t2.tag GROUP BY t1.cardid, t1.name
```

the result come out like this:

```
cardid      name      (no column name)
100         jane       8.00
200         Dan        5.00
399         Lisa       4.00
```

the last column on the result doesn't have a name (no column name). How do i modify my syntax to put a name on it (say 'Record').

Please note the last column without the name is actually the min(t2.record)

I'm using SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.cardid, 
       t1.Name, 
       min(t2.record) As YourPreferedName 
FROM   t2 
       INNER JOIN t1 
           on t1.tag = t2.tag 
GROUP BY t1.cardid, t1.name
```